# Building GEE timeseries for multiple locations

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, multipoint

I want to build a timeseries chart for multiple points.

Is it possible to use ui.Chart.image.series and have different lines for different points?

They are not regions, so I don't think .seriesByRegion is appropriate.

When I feed in a feature collection of points, it seems to pull the MODIS data and stretch it along as if it were one location, not parse it out by location like I want.

Code below.

MODIS data for my time of interest

```
var terraCollection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD10A1").select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover']).filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-11-01', '2020-05-01'))
```

Feature Collection of Points that I want to build a timeseries for

```
var points = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
    [[13.427963679755548, 60.28846585303612],
     [14.021225398505548, 60.87127944326994],
     [14.087143367255548, 60.08089287233658],
     [13.120346492255548, 60.02605006413671]]);
```

Current code for timeseries plot that seems to be merging all the points together:

```
var testChart = function(dataset) {return ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: dataset,
  region: points,
  }).setOptions({
  interpolateNulls: true,
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 3,
  title: 'NDSI over Time at a Single Location',
  vAxis: {title: 'NDSI'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  series: {
    0: {color: '#FF0000'}, // Point 1
    1: {color: '#FFFF00'}, // Point 2
    2: {color: '#00FF00'}, // Point 3
    3: {color: '#0000FF'}, // Point 4
  }
})}

print(testChart(terraCollection))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion`. Points are in the case also a *region*. However, this chart option will need a `ee.FeatureCollection` as input for the argument `regions`

```
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature( ee.Geometry.Point([13.427963679755548, 60.28846585303612])),
        ee.Feature( ee.Geometry.Point([14.021225398505548, 60.87127944326994])),
        ee.Feature( ee.Geometry.Point([14.087143367255548, 60.08089287233658])),
        ee.Feature( ee.Geometry.Point([13.120346492255548, 60.02605006413671]))]);
     
var testChart = function(dataset) {
  return ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: dataset,
    regions: points,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
    })
// .setOptions({...}) // set the options you like
}

print(testChart(terraCollection))
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/942cdf7482ea2d096c44a9d2f8cc7a74)

Comment: Thank you! What is the reducer doing in this case since each point is treated independently?

Comment: indeed, not that much for single points as geometry inputs.